# why am I getting this error? TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to learn the __iter__ method and this is the error I'm getting:

```
print(i for i in my_iter)
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'
```

My code is as follows:

```
class IterMethod:
    def __init__(self, last_elem):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        i = 5
        while i <= 50:
            print(f"this is {i}")
            i = i + 10
    
my_iter = IterMethod(60)

print(i for i in my_iter)
```

Can you please explain why? Thanks!

Comment: You need a ```yield i``` in your while block.   The question of where you want it, depends on whether you want i to be the value before or after the ```i = i + 10```.

Comment: What's the purpose of `last_elem`?

Comment: `last_elem` is useless here. I just wrote it in place of 50 in the while loop but forgot to delete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(My apologies,  in my haste to provide an answer, I hadn't explained why there was an error.  This edit is to include the explanation.)

Explanation:

The `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'`
means that `__iter__()` wasn't returning any values (by default, this means it's None for "No return value" (In this particular case)).  (Confusing, I know as that means it's technically returning None.)

`__iter__` must return a value each time it 'generates' a value from within the function.  If it doesn't return a value, you get the error.

Please note that when I say `return a value`, you don't use `return`.  In the case of **iter**  (which is basically a generator function), you need to use `yield`.  If you're confused with this, please read up on what generators are. i.e. at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generators-in-python/ (for example, and not affiliated to this link).

So...

Two issues plus one change (as suggested by @DanielWalker):

1. You could make it simpler by changing:

```
   i = i + 10
```

to

```
   i += 10
```

2. You need to change your `print(i for i in my_iter)`.

As is this prints the generator signature.  What you want is:

```
   print(list(i for i in my_iter))
```

3. You need to have a `yield` statement in your `__iter__` method.

Depending on if you want the `i` value to be, you have the following options:

```
class IterMethod:
    def __init__(self, last_elem):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        i = 5
        while i <= 50:
            print(f"this is {i}")
            i += 10
            yield i


my_iter = IterMethod(60)

print(list(i for i in my_iter))
```

So this will output:

```
this is 5
this is 15
this is 25
this is 35
this is 45
[15, 25, 35, 45, 55]
```

Now if you want to yield the `i` value before the `i = i + 10`,

```
class IterMethod:
    def __init__(self, last_elem):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        i = 5
        while i <= 50:
            print(f"this is {i}")
            yield i
            i += 10


my_iter = IterMethod(60)

print(list(i for i in my_iter))
```

This will output:

```
this is 5
this is 15
this is 25
this is 35
this is 45
[5, 15, 25, 35, 45]
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved the issue but could you please explain what the error msg is trying to say? `TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'` I don't understand the logic behind `non iterator of type none type`

Comment: @VRM The error is there because you are not returning or yeilding anything with the __iter__ method

Answer (score 1):

In short, you might have **forgotten the `return` keyword**, or the method your calling is actually returning `None`. **`__iter__` should return an iterable object.**

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._internal_dict)
```

Use a different method to return a generator:

```
def generator(self):
    for item in self._internal_dict.items()
        yield item
```